# Learn Enough Rails -- Non-admin user cannot log in via log_in_as

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following Michael Hertl's Learn Enough Rails tutorial, and I happened to notice that the `log_in_as` method hasn't been working for users that are not admin.
Originally, I was logging in `@admin_user` to test the method and it was working fine, but a different test starting failing later on. I traced it back to the `log_in_as` method not signing in non-admin users (namely, `@other_user`).

```
22:52:30 - INFO - Running: test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb
Running via Spring preloader in process 634866
Started with run options --seed 27389

 FAIL["test_log_in_as_method_works", #<Minitest::Reporters::Suite:0x000055ce9c593998 @name="UsersControllerTest">, 0.6345567099997425]
 test_log_in_as_method_works#UsersControllerTest (0.63s)
        Expected false to be truthy.
        test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:45:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
```

users_controller_test.rb (relevant portion):

```
  require 'test_helper'

class UsersControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest


  def setup
    @admin_user = users(:Danbug)
    @other_user = users(:Pepe)
    @unactivated_user = users(:Kaidabug)
  end

  test "log_in_as method works" do
    log_in_as(@other_user)                  # "log_in_as(@admin_user)' works as expected
    assert is_logged_in?
  end
```

test_helper (relevant portion):

```
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all
  include ApplicationHelper


  # Returns true if a user is logged in
  def is_logged_in?
    !session[:user_id].nil?
  end

  # Log in as a particular user (controller test)
  def log_in_as(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end
```

users.yml (I have a younger sister that has fun making up fake names for my tests):

```
Danbug:
  name: Danbug Buggaroo
  email: danbuggie@meowmail.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
  admin: true
  activated: true
  activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>

Pepe:
  name: Pepe Pepperton
  email: Pepe@meowmail.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
  admin: false
  activated: true
  activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>


Kaidabug:
  name: Kaidabug Buggaroo
  email: Kaidabuggie@meowmail.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
  activated: false
  activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>
```